# MINI_THUMB_MAGIC usage

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I wonder if I can use MINI_THUMB_MAGIC from MediaStore.Images.Media to create the Uri for the thumbnails, for example something like below:

"content://media/external/images/thumbnails/" + "kind_mini" +"/"+ thumbId

Answer (score 0):

JAVA

```
package app.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Test extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);

    imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/d2.jpg"));
  }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is at /res/layout/list.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    />

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="125dip"  android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:src="#555555"
    />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:maxWidth="35dip"  android:maxHeight="50dip"
    />

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to use the thumb_id from the  MediaStore.MediaColumns table to create the URI